# How to save contourf figure to image (.jpg) using matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, plot, contourf

I want to save figure of contourf to image (.jpg). i tried using saveas(gcf, output, 'jpg') and the result is blank .jpg file. Can you help me so the plot contourf can saving in my computer?

```
contourf(L, jml_level)
colormap autumn
figure
```

[This is result of contourf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxBk5.png)

Thankyou.

Comment: Did you try `print -djpeg filename`?

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I was trying to say. You have tried the `saveas` command. Did you also try the `print` command? You can save figures to a JPEG file with that command too.

Comment: i tried using print command and the result is same blank jpg

Comment: Wait, when you did `saveas(gcf,...)`, did you have the relevant figure as the current figure? The code you show where you make the plot, you end with `figure`. This will create a new, empty figure. `gcf` now is that empty figure. Please make sure you are not saving this empty figure.

Comment: Thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use figure handle to indicate which figure to save

```
fig1 = figure;
contourf(L, jml_level)
colormap autumn
saveas(fig1,'cont.png')
```